# Order Confirmation Emails

Tags: expresso-store, email

I am running Exp-resso store. When an order is placed the customer gets a confirmation email but the admin doesnt.

I am sure i am missing something very simple here but not sure what. Where do you set the email address order confirmations should go to? Is there a way of testing it?

I have coded my own custom payment gateway dont think this is the problem though as the order registers as payed within the system.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you improve your question by mentioning which e-commerce module you are using?

Comment: Done, apologies forgot to tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the store_order_complete_end extension hooks to execute custom code upon successful completion of an order https://expresso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html
2. If you want an easy solution without coding us the BCC field in the the control panel of exp-resso store, that is: Modules > Expresso Store > Settings > Email Templates > Edit Email Template.

Best, Daniel

Comment: The BCC field isnt working! Custom coding it is.

Comment: If the BCC field isn't working but the customer does get their copy, it's probably getting caught in a spam filter.

Comment: Thats the first thing i checked. Nothing in the spam filter. Where is the admin email set?

Comment: How do you mean admin email? You can set it in the BCC field under "Edit Email Template" as mentioned above. The current version of Store only allows one email per status, so BCC is the best way to give your client a copy of each order received.

Comment: I mean the admin email which all confirmation emails should go to (assuming it was working).

Comment: I should add that when an order is complete and has been paid i am using - return new Merchant_response(Merchant_response::COMPLETE, $orderId); - to complete the order.

Comment: Ok i got around this by running my own PHP mail() on the successful completion of an order.